# How pass more than one values in a Single variable to a Function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function

I am using vb.net

I have a Function in my class(class1) file namely save. This Save function have 3 arguments. Now i am using the following approach to send arguments.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
        dim p as new class1
        p.save(txtempid.text,txtempname.text,txtage.text)
        messagebox.show("Successfully Saved")
End sub
```

Class1:

```
imports system.data.sqlclient
imports system.configuration
public class class1
    Dim constr As String
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

public function save(byval s as string,byval s1 as string,byval s2 as string)
    constr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("con")
    con = New SqlConnection(constr)
    con.Open()
    cmd=new sqlcommand("Emp_insert",con)
    cmd.commandtype=commandtype.storedprocedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = s
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = s1
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = s2
    cmd.executenonquery()
    cmd.dispose()
    con.close()
   return 0
End function
End Class
```

It's ok, but when i have more numerber of arguments it's hard. can any one suggest me better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification

```
public function save(parameters as Dictionary(Of string, object)) as int
for each item as KeyvaluePair(Of string, object) in parameters
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & item.Key, item.Value)
next
return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
end function
```

You can use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)

```
public sub DoSomething(Tuple (Of string, string, integer) myparameter)
dim firstItem as string = myparameter.Item1 
dim secondItem as string = myparameter.Item2
dim thirdItem as integer = myparameter.Item3
end sub

sub main()
Dim tuple as New Tuple(Of string, string, integer)("First","Second", 100)
DoSomething(tuple)
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am newer to vb.net. So i am unable to understand this tuple concept. can u explain little bit deeply or please guide me with if any other approach

Comment: You can create a Tuple, and pass the tuple variable to the function.

Comment: i think tuple was supported from framework 4. But i am using framework2

Comment: yes. for .net 2.0 you may need to use struct or class. Alternative, you can use Params

Comment: Thanks, i am trying with struct,class